# Laravel calling model class method in class's static created method

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following code that will dispatch a job once a model is created

```
class Foo extends Model {

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function (Foo $foo) {

            dispatch(function() use ($foo) {
                $foo->bar();
            });

        });
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        $this->baz = "";
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

This is the error that I got in my log

```
Call to undefined method App\Models\Foo::bar() {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Call to undefined method App\\Models\\Foo::bar() at ...../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:50)
```

Question: How do I call bar() in my static::created method?

=======================================================

As of now I am using this approach, even though I dislike this approach

```
class Foo extends Model {

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function (Foo $foo) {
            $foo_id = $foo->id;

            dispatch(function() use ($foo_id) {
                $foo = Foo::find($foo_id);
                $foo->bar();
            });

        });
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        $this->baz = "";
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You bar() function is not static. You should create model first by using $foo = new Foo. Than call $foo->bar()

Comment: It doesn't need to be. `$foo` should be an instance of the model

Comment: as what @DevK said, the $foo variable is already instantiated, the below approach will work

    `static::created(function() use ($foo) {
        $foo->baz = "";
        $foo->save();
    });`

But this doesn't work

    `static::created(function() use ($foo) {
        $foo->bar();
    });`